# Comparing Edges to determine if a difference in an angle requires clockwise or counter clockwise rotation to match

Tags: python, rotation

In python, I have a script that I can use to determine the difference in angles between two edges:

```
#python
import math
def uDirection (v1, v2):
    return (v2[0]-v1[0], v2[1]-v1[1])
def dotUV (u1, u2):
    return (u1[0]*u2[0] + u1[1]*u2[1])
def uLength (u):
    return math.sqrt(dotUV(u,u))    
def uNormalize (u):
    r = [0.0] * 2
    u_len = uLength(u)
    if u_len > 0.0:
        u_invLen = 1.0 / u_len
        r[0] = u[0] * u_invLen
        r[1] = u[1] * u_invLen
    return r
def angle(dotProduct):
    return math.degrees(math.acos(dotProduct))
p1,p2 = (0,0),(1,1) #<---- edge 1
p3,p4 = (0,0),(1,0) #<---- edge 2
dir = uDirection(p1,p2)
dir2 = uDirection(p3,p4)
dir_n = uNormalize(dir)
dir2_n = uNormalize(dir2)
dotProduct = dotUV(dir_n, dir2_n)
ang1 = angle(dotProduct)
#ang1 = 45
```

The angle of difference is 45 degrees, if I want to then rotate edge 2 (p3,p4) to match edge 1 (p1,p2), I need to determine if the rotation needed is clockwise or counterclockwise.  Currently its counter-clockwise but if the positions of the edges were reversed, it would still give me 45 degrees of difference but the direction edge 2 would have to move would be clockwise.  Is there a way I can modify what I have to determine clockwise v. counterclockwise?

Comment: Just a side note: You are mixing tuples and lists. Holding vectors as tuples makes them immutable, essentially rendering in-place modification impossible. And, your normalized vector is 3-dimensional. Is that intended?

Comment: Oh it should be 2D since this is being applied to UV coordinates of geometry, its a modification from a 3D script, I must have missed the 3 but it still functions, changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Let the two vectors `e1` and `e2`. I assume you seek to rotate *the smalles angle* between these two:

```
if e1[0] * e2[1] - e1[0] * e2[1] < 0:
    pass # Rotate CW
else
    pass # Rotate CCW
```

Should do the trick.

If you intend to rotate `e2` step-wise on a timely basis, you need to control your rotation speed along with the `dt` (time delta between current and last frame) similar to:

```
rotspeed = .5 # Whatever suits your framerate and desired speed
if e1[0] * e2[1] - e1[0] * e2[1] < 0:
    angle = 2 * math.pi - rotspeed * dt # Rotate CW
else:
    angle = rotspeed * dt # Rotate CCW

x = math.cos(math.atan2(e2[0], e2[1]) + angle)
y = math.sin(math.atan2(e2[0], e2[1]) + angle)

next_e2 = [x, y]
```

Comment: Actually I always want to rotate counter clockwise, I just want to determine if the direction edge 2 would have to move is clockwise or counter-clockwise, if its counter clockwise I use the resulting angle, if its clockwise I can just subtract the angle from 360 to get its counter-clockwise rotation, no?

Comment: Well, this essentially is what I proposed: If the condition holds, the angle between the two edges needs to be interpreted as the required angle to be covered in *clockwise* direction, otherwise you need to cover it in *counter-clockwise* direction. As my second code snippet outlines, the *angle to go* is either `2 * pi - angle` or just the `angle` itself, depending on required rotation direction.

Comment: I seem to only be getting CCW rotation even when its offset I'd need is clockwise... I'm assuming dir and dir2 in my example = e1, e2 in yours?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get a `45` both ways is because the `cos` function is an *even function*, so both negative and positive dot products of the same magnitude will map to the same value.

You could use the *arcsin* of the `dotProduct` to determine the sign of the angle which translates to the direction of rotation:

```
def angle(dotProduct):
    sign = math.asin(dotProduct) // abs(math.asin(dotProduct))
    return sign * math.degrees(math.acos(dotProduct))
```

A `+ve` will mean clockwise and `-ve` coounterclockwise, or vice-versa.

Comment: Hmmm when I plug in the function it gives me 45 either way I run it, is it supposed to result in a 45/-45 result depending on which value is (0,0),(1,1) and (0,0),(1,0)?

Comment: You reversed the values `(0,0),(1,1) <> (0,0),(1,0)`?

Comment: Yes.
    p1,p2 = (0,0),(1,1)
    p3,p4 = (0,0),(1,0)
    to
    p3,p4 = (0,0),(1,1)
    p1,p2 = (0,0),(1,0)

Comment: You're taking directions within each edge not across the two, so switching is only a matter of changing names. Why does `uDirection` take `P1` and `P2`, and not `P1` and `P3`?

Comment: Testing it, it appears that if I take the value to something like (0,0),(-0.1,1) or (0,0),(-0.1,-1) it does give me a negative angle, but it doesn't appear to differentiate correctly, for instance edge 1 (0,0),(-0.0001,1) compared to edge 2 (0,0),(1,0) returns -90.005 which is 'correct' since its a counter clockwise rotation from edge 2 to edge 1 of roughly 90 degrees.  

 But, if I make  edge 1 (0,0),(-0.0001,-1) compared to edge 2 (0,0),(1,0) it still returns -90.005 which is incorrect it should be 90.005 instead.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, what comparing p1 and p3 would do since they occupy the same space???